# What am I doing wrong? Removing duplicates using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I'm new to VBA so this is probably a very obvious mistake.

To keep it short, I am trying to delete rows based on two criteria: In Column A, if they have the same value (duplicate) and in Column B, the difference is *less than* 100, then one row is deleted from the bottom.

Example data:

```
Column A  Column B          
1         300              
1         350     SHOULD be deleted as second column diff. is <100 compared to row above
2         500              
2         700     Should NOT be deleted as second column diff. is not <100
```

Here is the code I have come up with:

```
Sub deduplication()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lrow To 2 Step -1
        For j = i To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = .Cells(j, "A").Value And .Cells(i, "B").Value - .Cells(j, "B").Value < 100 Then
               .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

This largely works, but only if the second criterion is *greater than* (>) rather than *less than* (<). When it is less than, it deletes **every row**. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easy fix?

Thank you

Comment: do you need to take the absolute value of the difference? Also, check your parentheses with chained expressions.

Comment: Consider using a helper column, this would make the vba code easier. Example Column C (e.g. Cell C3): `=IF(AND(A2=A3, ABS(B3-B2)>100),"Delete", "Keep")`. Then your vba code can simply loop backwards over column c and delete those that have "Delete". I like @urdearboy's answer below, but the use of helper columns is a handy technique for more complex problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not

```
If .Cells(i, "A").Value = .Cells(j, "A").Value And .Cells(i, "B").Value - .Cells(j, "B").Value < 100 Then
```

Here in the second part of the statement, you're just comparing `.Cells(j, "B").Value` to const 100 !

But

```
If .Cells(i, "A").Value = .Cells(j, "A").Value And Abs(.Cells(i, "B").Value - .Cells(j, "B").Value) < 100 Then
```

Abs() may help, else keep just the ( )

Comment: I agree with using `Abs()` since otherwise the comparison will sometimes fail (i.e. looking for a difference greater than 10: `4-50>10` will evaluate to false as 4-50 => **-** 45, which is less then 10). However, the comparison **is** actually doing a subtraction there.

Comment: A bit of a late reply but thanks, this was the small thing I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim ACell As Range
    Dim hUnq As Object

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set hUnq = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    Set rData = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If rData.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub  'No data

    For Each ACell In rData.Cells
        If Not hUnq.Exists(ACell.Value) Then
            'New Unique ACell value
            hUnq.Add ACell.Value, ACell.Value
        Else
            'Duplicate ACell value
            If Abs(ws.Cells(ACell.Row, "B").Value - ws.Cells(ACell.Row - 1, "B").Value) < 100 Then
                If rDel Is Nothing Then Set rDel = ACell Else Set rDel = Union(rDel, ACell)
            End If
        End If
    Next ACell

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to the format of your code, you can do this using one `For` loop as well.

```
For i = lrow To 3 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, "A") = .Cells(i - 1, "A") And (.Cells(i, "B") - .Cells(i - 1, "B")) < 100 Then
        .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Every first j-cycle starts off by comparing a row to itself since you start with `j = i`. The difference between a value and itself is always zero. (It also compares row 2 with itself as the very last step.)

However, if you switch:

```
For i = lrow To 2 Step -1
For j = i To 2 Step -1
```

to:

```
For i = lrow To 3 Step -1
For j = i - 1 To 2 Step -1`
```

the code will compare all the various rows without the self-compares.

Another point (which @Proger_Cbsk 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330166/9259306) brought to mind), is that doing the comparison with just the subtraction `.Cells(i, "B").Value - .Cells(j, "B").Value < 100` will sometimes cause unexpected results.

For example, assume `.Cells(i, "B").Value = 1` and `.Cells(j, "B").Value = 250`. We can tell by just looking, that there is a difference of at least 100, so you would expect this part of the expression to evaluate to False. However, from straight substitution, you get the expression: `1 - 250 < 100`. Since `1 - 250 = -249`, and since `-249 < 100`, the expression would actually evaluate to True.

However, if you were to change `.Cells(i, "B").Value - .Cells(j, "B").Value < 100` to `Abs(.Cells(i, "B").Value - .Cells(j, "B").Value) < 100`, the expression will now be looking at if the **difference** is greater or less than 100, instead of looking at if the **subtraction result** is greater or less than 100.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the built-in command:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A:$A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

[Range.RemoveDuplicates Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)